# git set upstream to remote folder in a repository

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket, pull, upstream-branch

I currently have a repository with 3 separate directories in it. There's two remote servers and my local machine that currently have a copy of the entire repository in each. Is there a way I can set the upstream and origin for these remote machines to a specific folder in the parent repository?

something like

git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo**/pathToSubdirectory**.git

or do I need to make a separate repository for each folder?

For example, if I'm on server A I'd like to run git pull and have it pull from the remote repository/folderA.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You might be trying to make a [sparse checkout.](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-read-tree) This means you can checkout only the directory structure of a repository and then select which objects to fetch.
[Here](https://briancoyner.github.io/2013/06/05/git-sparse-checkout.html) is a straightforward six-step tutorial how you could sparse-checkout only one (or two, if you like) of your three directories.

Or you might want to use a [submodule](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) for each of the three directories. Then they're three separate repositories but you can checkout your whole directory structure using `git clone --recurse-submodules`

It is not possible to set upstream to a subdirectory the way you described it.

Comment: Was it successful?

Comment: I was still having issues getting it to work. I ended up switching to subversion where you can check out sub repos.